# In b tree data structure, when does height decrease?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

In b tree data structure, when does height decrease?

I know when the b tree height is incremented by 1
- When in the root node happens overflow, so when the root node splits, the height of b tree incremented.

However, I want to know when the height of b tree data structure decrease?

Comment: What about a balancing operation, or when you remove an element?

Answer (score 2):

When a key in a b-tree *T* is deleted, there are cases when some of the nodes involved in the deleting operation remain with the number of keys less than tree degree (call it *t*). In such cases, some of the nodes require merging, so again all nodes of the given B tree have at least *t - 1* keys. Obviously, consecutive deleting nodes causes merging nodes, which further causes dropping of the entire node (by moving its keys to another node). When all nodes in a tree level are dropped, tree height decreases.